# Bluetooth file transfers from Sony Arc S always get interrupted

Tags: bluetooth, sony-xperia-arc

I am not able to transfer files completely over Bluetooth because the the transfers keep getting interrupted. My phone model is a Sony Arc S LT8i.

I tried to send a 700 kb image file to my Mac and it started to transfer but got interrupted when 90% of it was transferred. Similarly, I tried to send the same file to a Samsung Galaxy Ace phone and it sent 99% of the file when it got interrupted, at which point the receving phone (Ace) showed a message stating "Remote device disconnected". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I once got that on my Xperia phone when I was transferring a 150 MB file over bluetooth.

Some things you can try:

- Try transferring another file. If it transfers, send the other file.
- If your phone is too close to the other device try moving your phone away from it.
- Turn off bluetooth, then turn it back on.
- Pair the device(s) with the phone.